# Performing If statement on a Textblock in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, textblock

**Question:**

Trying to essentially say IF my TextBlock contains "X" THEN Perform the IF but I don't know how to write that in the correct context.

**Example:**

If the word "Chocolate" is in the TextBlock I'd like to show an Image of "Chocolate" (I already know how to correctly display the image, my problem is with the IF Statement itself)

I'm new to this kinda stuff and I'd like like to know for future reference.

**Problems:**

Right now, I don't know HOW to perform an IF statement on a TextBlock/String in a way that actually works.

**Attempted:**

```
 if (string content.contains("Chocolate"));
        {

            Uri Pure = new Uri("Images/ChocolatePortrait.png", UriKind.Relative);
            BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage(Pure);
            image2.Source = imageSource;


        }
```

---

```
if (textBlock.text = ("Chocolate"));
        {

            Uri Pure = new Uri("Images/ChocolatePortrait.png", UriKind.Relative);
            BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage(Pure);
            image2.Source = imageSource;


        }
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: Look up "string comparison c#" in google. It can be tricky starting out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are terminating the if-statement prematurely by a semicolon `;`!

```
if (textBlock.Text.Contains("Chocolate")) // <= removed the ";"
{
    Uri Pure = new Uri("Images/ElfPortrait.png", UriKind.Relative);
    BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage(Pure);
    image2.Source = imageSource;
}
```

Also the property is `Text` with an upper case "T". In C# `Text` and `text` are two different identfiers!

Many programmers prefer to write the opening brace on the same line. This makes it clearer that the end of the line is not the end of a statement:

```
if (condition) {
    statement-sequence
}
```

---

Note that `"The Chocolate is fine!".Contains("Chocolate")` returns `true`. If the whole string must be equal to the word then compare with `textBlock.Text == "Chocolate"`

Answer (score 2):

use == to test for equality

```
if (textBlock.Text == "Chocolate")
        {

            Uri Pure = new Uri("Images/ChocolatePortrait.png", UriKind.Relative);
            BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage(Pure);
            image2.Source = imageSource;


        }
```

you could also do something like this:

```
if (textBlock.Text.Contains("Chocolate", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  // ....
}
```

*if you're looking for the word "chocolate" in the text block's text and you don't want the check to be case sensitive*.

Comment: He *doesn't* want to check for equality though, or at least that's what it sounds like.

Comment: Note that textBlock is a TERRIBLE name for a textblock. If he is actually using the class name, that won't work and will need to change to an actual instance name.

Comment: I read his post as wanting to check for equality, like where he says, "If the word "Chocolate" is in the TextBlock I'd like to..."

Answer (score 0):

```
if(YOUR_STRING_HERE.Contains(STRING_YOU_WANT_TO_FIND))
{
   //do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either check for equality with:

```
if (textBlock.text.Equals("Chocolate");
{
//do whatever must be done here
}
```

Or you can also use == (then you dont need to check for null before).
However, with the 'Equals' you can also use the overload functions e.g. to ignore the case.

Comment: This will throw an exception if the text is null.  Also note that the `==` operator is overloaded for strings to perform a comparison of the *value* of the string, not it's reference.  Using `==` would be *superior*, not inferior.

Comment: Thanks, This worked! I feel like an idiot. I'll accept this as the answer when It allows me too.

And the way this works is the text is never going to be Null, the user is required to click ona  button which populates the text in the Textblock.

Sounds stupid, I know. But I'm a relatively new programmer (Only jumped from VB months ago)

Comment: @Servy I strongly believe, == does the same thing in the background. Besides, textBlock.text will never be null, unless you set it to null.
Also, you can use the overloads of Equals. But of course you can also use == to compare two strings.

Comment: @Servy however, I edited my answer since it sounded too much like 'rather use equals than =='. I think it's a matter of opinion too.

Comment: @FabianBigler You went out of your way to suggest the use of `Equals` instead of the use of `==`.  This is implying that `==` is in some way inappropriate.  It is not.

Comment: @Servy You're right, my first answer was unhappily stated. Improved it now, thank you.

Comment: The fact that string is a reference type has nothing to do with this decision.